# Why doesn't text.replace("old", "new") change the text variable?

Tags: python

I am just learning python and wanted to create a little program which changes words in a string.
But for some reason it doesn't work how i intended.

here is the code i try to run.

```
#setting text as variable
text= "hi my name is john"

#replacing the names
text.replace ("john", "peter")

#printing the new string
print (text)
```

for my understanding of the function replace () shouldn't it replace john with peter?
or what is my mistake?

thanks in advance

Comment: `replace` doesn't change the object you pass into it but returns a new string with the replaced substring

Comment: the original string is not modified, use `text=text.replace("john", "peter")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the replace function returns a new string object and is not assigned to the text variable. use:

```py
#setting text as variable
text= "hi my name is john"

#replacing the names 
text = text.replace ("john", "peter")

#printing the new string
print (text)
```

Comment: In [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), see the section *Answer Well-Asked Questions*, and therein the bullet point regarding questions that "have been asked and answered many times before".

Answer (score -1):

String is immutable,so you must create new string variable

```
text_2=text.replace("john","peter")
Print(text_2)
```